# c++ [&] operator

Tags: c++, c++11

hello i have found this code on windows documentation

but i don't get what means

```
[&]
```

just please can you clear me what it should do ??

it is not c++ standard true??

This is the code:

```cs
void parallel_matrix_multiply(double** m1, double** m2, double** result, size_t size)
{
   parallel_for (size_t(0), size, [&](size_t i)
   {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
      {
         double temp = 0;
         for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
         {
            temp += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
         }
         result[i][j] = temp;
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is feature of `C++11` standard. [lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B)

Answer (score 37):

It introduces a lambda expression. The contents of the square brackets
indicate what is to be captured inside the lambda. Having only a `&`
in there means that everything that is mentioned inside the lambda and
can be found outside of its scope is captured by reference.

Example:

```
int a = 0;
auto l = [&]() { 
  ++a; // a refers to the a outside of this scope through a reference
}
l(); // execute the lambda
```

Comment: this is a nice example... i like the Comment inside the function it makes more clear the & meaning

Comment: So if i write [=] and i edit the a variable then ouside the lambda function the value is changed ? or it is not because was not passed by reference ?

Comment: @frank: if you just change & to = it won't compile because you cannot mutate copied variables unless you explicitly say that you intend to do so with the mutable keyword.

Comment: thx for the answer but in the end after the lambda execution when a is mutable the value will not change right?

Answer (score 22):

It is a C++11 feature and is called the *lambda capture clause*. In this case, the `[&]` makes available to the lambda function all of the arguments to the `parallel_matrix_multiply()` function by reference.

See [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for more information.

Comment: "makes all of the arguments of the `parallel_matrix_multiply() function` available by reference to the lambda function"?

Comment: @SteveJessop, the `[&]` makes all variables in scope available in the body of the lambda function by reference, including the arguments to the function `parallel_matrix_multiply()`. Is this incorrect or just confusingly phrased?

Comment: It's correct (as far as I understand it: I don't know whether there are any confusing edge cases). My comment was just trying to make the sentence a bit less unwieldy, sorry if I didn't convey that.

Answer (score 10):

This is the capture clause used for lambda expressions. A lambda expression can have access to all variables of it's enclosing scope (i.e. if the lambda is within a function it can have access to all variables inside that function). The `[&]` means that the lambda will get all the variables *by reference*. They can also be taken *by value*, in that case you would use `[=]`. you can also specify concrete variables that need to be taken in a specific way, for example this code:

```
[&X, =]
```

means that lambda will take the `X` variable by reference, and all others by value.

Comment: So if i write [=] and i edit a variable .... then ouside the lambda function the value is changed ? i suppose not .. right?

Comment: @frank, yes, if you write [=], the value outside the lambda will stay the same, no matter what you do.

Comment: It's equivalent to passing a variable by value to a regular function: the caller's copy doesn't change. You can easily confirm this yourself with a toy example.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217956/error-variable-cannot-be-implicitly-captured-because-no-default-capture-mode-h), lambda functions have *no* access to variables of their enclosing scope by default.

Answer (score 6):

[&] means that you will have access to variables from surrounding code inside lambda expression, and it will be access by referenc (i.e. you can modify them). In the example code, you can see that `m1, m2, result` and `size` are used in lambda experssion even though they are not passed as parameters.

Comment: Technically you can't modify the variables either way, since lambdas which are not explicitely specified as `mutable` have a `const` `operator()`, so captured variables can't be changed. For `mutable` lambdas the variables can be changed in both cases, however the change is visible outside the lambda only for capture by reference

Answer (score 4):

This is a Lambda function, C++ 11 feature

```
[&](size_t i){...}
```

will act like a callback or functor. So you don't need to write another function somewhere else to pass to parallel_for.