# Error: variable "cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified"

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am trying  to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478636/stdremove-if-lambda-not-removing-anything-from-the-collection) to use a lambda with `remove_if`. Here is my attempt:

```
int flagId = _ChildToRemove->getId();
auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_FinalFlagsVec.begin(), m_FinalFlagsVec.end(), 
        [](Flag& device) { 
            return device.getId() == flagId; 
        });

m_FinalFlagsVec.erase(new_end, m_FinalFlagsVec.end());
```

but this fails to compile:

```
error C3493: 'flagId' cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified
```

How can I include the outside parameter, `flagId`,  in the lambda expression?

Comment: Default capture modes are `[=]` (by value) and `[&]` (by reference). `[ ]` means no capture.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You must specify `flagId` to be captured. That is what the `[]` part is for. Right now it doesn't capture anything. You can capture ([more info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture)) by value or by reference. Something like:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_FinalFlagsVec.begin(), m_FinalFlagsVec.end(),
        [&flagId](Flag& device)
    { return device.getId() == flagId; });
```

Which captures by reference. If you want to capture by const value, you can do this:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_FinalFlagsVec.begin(), m_FinalFlagsVec.end(),
        [flagId](Flag& device)
    { return device.getId() == flagId; });
```

Or by mutable value:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_FinalFlagsVec.begin(), m_FinalFlagsVec.end(),
        [flagId](Flag& device) mutable
    { return device.getId() == flagId; });
```

Sadly there is no straightforward way to capture by `const` reference until C++17. I personally would just declare a temporary `const` ref and capture that by ref:

```
const auto& tmp = flagId;
auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_FinalFlagsVec.begin(), m_FinalFlagsVec.end(),
            [&tmp](Flag& device)
        { return device.getId() == tmp; }); //tmp is immutable
```

In C++17 and beyond we can capture by const-reference by using [`as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const)

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_FinalFlagsVec.begin(), m_FinalFlagsVec.end(),
            [&flagId = std::as_const(flagId)](Flag& device)
        { return device.getId() == flagId; });
```

Answer (score 9):

It won't let me comment because I don't have enough "points" but to reply to AndyG there is an easy way to capture by const reference now:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_FinalFlagsVec.begin(), m_FinalFlagsVec.end(),
        [&flagId = as_const(flagId)](Flag& device)
    { return device.getId() == flagId; });
```