# Complementary indexes to find() in Armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

Basic question from a newcomer to Armadillo and C++ from R.

I have a vector `X` and I want to set the entries below `0` to a given value and the ones larger than `0` to another. Armadillo has the `find` function for returning [*indices of elements of X that are non-zero or satisfy a relational condition*](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find) (not logical!?) so I can do:

```
arma::uvec ind0 = find(X < 0);
arma::uvec ind1 = find(X >= 0);

X(ind0).zeros();
X(ind1).fill(1);
```

This is clearly not the best solution. What would be a better way that does not involve calling `find` two times?

Comment: you can use std::transform and perform all the changes at 1 time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [.transform()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#transform) member function. Requires C++11 compiler.

```
mat X(100,100,fill::randu);

X -= 0.5;

X.transform( [](double val) { return (val < 0) ? double(0) : double(1); } );
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! (+1) As a small comment, if you want to use an external variable inside the lambda function it is necessary to pass it inside the square brackets (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217956/error-variable-cannot-be-implicitly-captured-because-no-default-capture-mode-h/30217989).

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need! It will make values smaller than 0, equal to 0 and values bigger than 1 equal to 1.

```
 X = clamp(X, 0, 1);
```

more info at:
http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#clamp