# Fails to capture in a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, compiler-errors, compilation, c++14

Here is a reproducible code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class X
{
public:
 int a; 
  X(int b)
  : a(b)
  {}
};

int main()
{
  // Build the vector 'v'
  std::vector<X> v;
  X x1(7);
  v.push_back(x1);
  X x2(11);
  v.push_back(x2);
  X x3(16);
  v.push_back(x3);
  X x4(20);
  v.push_back(x4);
  X x5(22);
  v.push_back(x5);
  X x6(31);
  v.push_back(x6);
  X x7(38);
  v.push_back(x7);

  // Search if there is an element of 'v' which attribute 'a' equals 18
  int y(18); 
  if (
    std::find(
        v.begin(),
        v.end(),
        [&](const X& o){return o.a == y;}
      ) == v.end()
    )
  {
    std::cout << "'y' is not present in 'v'\n";
  } else
  {
    std::cout << "'y' is present in 'v'\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I try to compile with `g++ -std=c++14 a.cpp -o a` and get

```
 error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('X' and 'const (lambda at a.cpp:38:5)')
```

I have tried a number of alternatives and read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) and a number of SE posts including [Error: variable “cannot be implicitly captured because no default capture mode has been specified”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217956/error-variable-cannot-be-implicitly-captured-because-no-default-capture-mode-h/30217989) but I fail to see my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `std::find()` with arguments that you should use with `std::find_if()`.

If you use `std::find()` the third argumend should be a value of the container; a `class X` instance, in this case.

If you want that the third argument is an unary predicate (that receive a container value and return a `bool`), the right function is `std::find_if()`.

Using a unary predicate as third argument for `std::find()`, the compiler try to equate a `class X` instance with the lambda function.

That is: the compiler try to compile

```
*(v.begin()) == [&](const X& o){return o.a == y;}
```

So the compiler error.

So try with

```
std::find_if(  // <-- std::find_if !
    v.begin(),
    v.end(),
    [&](const X& o){return o.a == y;}
  ) == v.end()
```

Comment: Thank you +1! If I may ask a follow-up question is there an equivalent to `find_if` for a binary search such as `binary_search_if`?

Comment: @Remi.b - as far I know... no: there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `std::find`, which, at third argument it expected the value to be compared, you need to provide an `operator==` to perform comparison.

You can try something like this:

```
(...)
bool operator==(const X& x, int b)
{
    return x.a == b;
}
```

and change `std::find` to:

```
std::find(
    v.begin(),
    v.end(),
    y
) == v.end()
```

but I prefer just changing `std::find` to `std::find_if`