# What does [&] mean before function?

Tags: c++

What does the following code mean?

```
auto allowed = [&](int x, const std::vector<int>&vect){

....

}
```

I mean, what does `[&]` do? Is it a function with the same name of the variable?

Because it is used in this way: `unsigned short ok = get_allowed(0, vect);`

Comment: It's a capture list for a lambda (c.f http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda )

Comment: It is not a function but a lambda. You should read up on those

Comment: Just a heads up, I closed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262019/c-operator) as a dupe of this question.  IMHO the answers here are more detailed.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

It means that the lambda function will capture all variables in the scope by **reference**.

To use other variables other than what was passed to lambda within it, we can use `capture-clause []`. 
You can capture by both reference and value, which you can specify using & and = respectively:

- `[=]` capture all variables within scope by value
- `[&]` capture all variables within scope by reference
- `[&var]` capture `var` by reference
- `[&, var]` specify that the default
  way of capturing is by reference and we want to capture `var`
- `[=, &var]` capture the variables in scope by value by default, but capture `var` using reference
  instead

Comment: Good point *by references*. Upvoted.

Comment: Of course the one that's missing in C++11 at least is the ability to capture a single class member variable. You have to fail over to good-old-fashioned function objects in that case.

Comment: Correctly pointed, we need to capture `this` pointer in the case of class member variable.

Comment: which kinda sucks!

Comment: @Bathsheba: There is still the workaround: `auto& member_alias = this->member; auto l = [&member_alias]() {...};`

Comment: ^ precisely what I do.

Answer (score 19):

It's a *lambda capture list* and has been defined in C++ from the C++11 standard.

`[&]` It means that you're wanting to access every variable *by reference* currently in scope within the lambda function.

It's your job to ensure that the referred objects are still in scope at the point the [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions) is invoked, else the program behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: The third paragraph here is the important thing!  If you never use `[&]` in a c++ program, that's fine.  But if you ever use it without fully grocking this third paragraph, you are probably writing buggy and dangerous software.

Answer (score 12):

It defines a Lambda expression, which is basically a function without a name. It has parameter list `(int x, const std::vector<int>&vect)` and a function body `{ ... }`. But it also has a capture list in the beginning `[&]`. If you want to access a variable (which is not a parameter) from the body of the lambda expression, you have to make the expression "take the variable with itself", so that the variable can be used later when the lambda expression will be executed.

You can either provide a list of variables, or use "all" to capture all of them. `[&]` means capturing all of them by reference, and `[=]` would mean to capture all of them by value.

(If you use `[&]`, note that the lambda body will use the value of the variable at the time the lambda is executed, and not the value which was valid when you created the lambda! This is because you do not have a copy of the value, only a reference to it.)

Comment: Upvoted; nice point made at the end. Do feel free to mention the dangling reference case as I allude to in my answer.

Comment: Upvoted for the point you made at the end as well.